# `delay` on `interval` will throw `NoSuchElementException`?

Tags: scala, rx-scala, reactivex

Some simple [rxscala](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala) code:

```
val s = Observable.interval(Duration("100 millis"))
       .zip(Seq(1, 2, 3)).map(_._2).delay(Duration("2 s"))
println(s.toBlocking.toList)
```

When run it, it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqLike$$anon$1.next(LinearSeqLike.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:31)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZipIterable$1.onNext(OperatorZipIterable.java:65)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:55)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimerPeriodically$1.call(OnSubscribeTimerPeriodically.java:51)
    at rx.Scheduler$Worker$1.call(Scheduler.java:120)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in RxJava. It has been fixed in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/3528 and you have to wait for the next release. However, you can use `Observable.interval(Duration("100 millis")).zip(Observable.from(Seq(1, 2, 3))).map(_._2).delay(Duration("2 s"))` as a workaround.